# Onclick is not working in google chrome for the alternate times in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button in my aspx page which has on click event.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
            Text="Save changes" />
```

Now the Button2_click is not called for the alternate times, i.e. it will be called when clicked for 2nd,4th,6th..but not for the 1st,3rd,5th... time.

The pageload is called each time but the button_click is not called.This is working fine in IE but having this issue in chrome.

Please tell me what can be done over this.

**Update**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        contentID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["contentid"]);
        if (contentID != 0)
        {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                getContentBody(contentID);
                TextBox1.Text = content;
                msg_lbl.Text="Inside if"+content;
                }
                else{
                msg_lbl.Text="Inside else";
                }

            }


            else
                Response.Write("Invalid URL for article");


    }

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //string textboxvalue = Request.Form[TextBox1.UniqueID];
            Response.Write("Inside button");
            mycon.Open();
            string query = "update content set content='" +TextBox1.Text + "' where contentID= '"+contentID +"'";
            msg_lbl.Text = query;
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command1 = mycon.CreateCommand();
                command1.CommandText = query;
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mycon.Close();
                getContentBody(contentID);
                TextBox1.Text = content;
                //msg_lbl.Text = "text" + TextBox1.Text;
               // msg_lbl.Text = "text" + TextBox1.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg_lbl.Text = "Exception in saving data" + ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                mycon.Close();

            }


    }
```

Comment: Post your page load event and/or the button click event.  I cannot reproduce this in google chrome, it works correctly.

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: You will need to further debug this.  Check the value of ContentID when you click the button, cause a post back.

Comment: The code is working fine in IE and it has nothing to do with contentID I believe.The portion in else gets executed i.e. postback but the button click is not called as I am printing one message in the first line of button click method

Comment: Usually when one states it works fine in IE, that means it shouldn't be working at all :).  I'm being serious...are you running in compatibility mode, what version of IE.  Does it work in firefox, does everything on the site validate according to the web cons?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using a `LisView` and your `AlternatingItemTemplate` has no event declared:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save changes" />
```

Comment: ,I pasted the code above for my aspx page but as you can see there is event defined here but the problem is with the google chrome because in IE it is running quite fine